# ':' sign causing {"There is an error in XML document (2, 6)."}

Tags: c#, xml

Xml reading problem.

```
private DataPDU Deserialize(string filepath)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataPDU));

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath, utf8);

        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);  //error raising here
        DataPDU XmlData = (DataPDU)obj;
        reader.Close();
        return XmlData;
    }
```

If I remove "Saa:" from the tag my code works fine. But the file providers give the in file in above format. Can you please help. Part of error trace bellow.

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=There is an error in XML document (2, 6).
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:                      
       Message=<DataPDU xmlns='urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0'> was not expected.
       Source=Microsoft.GeneratedCode
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDataPDU.Read9_DataPDU()
       InnerException:
```

xml file sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Saa:DataPDU xmlns:Saa="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0" xmlns:Sw="urn:swift:snl:ns.Sw" xmlns:SwGbl="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwGbl" xmlns:SwInt="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwInt" xmlns:SwSec="urn:swift:snl:ns.SwSec">
     <Saa:Body>
      <AppHdr:AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:AppHdr="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
       <Fr>
        <FIId>
         <FinInstnId>
          <BICFI>ABBLBDDH</BICFI>
         </FinInstnId>
        </FIId>
       </Fr>
       <To>
        <FIId>
         <FinInstnId>
          <BICFI>BBHOBDDHRTG</BICFI>
         </FinInstnId>
        </FIId>
       </To>
       <BizMsgIdr>MRQ140527142125236</BizMsgIdr>
       <MsgDefIdr>pacs.008.001.04</MsgDefIdr>
       <BizSvc>RTGS_CSCT</BizSvc>
       <CreDt>2014-05-27T14:21:25</CreDt>
      </AppHdr:AppHdr>      
     </Saa:Body>
    </Saa:DataPDU>
```

Comment: What is the definition – including the XML serialization attributes – of `DataPDU`? Have you [specified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.namespace.aspx) the namespace in those attributes?

Comment: What a stupid i am... :( ... Thanks a ton sir... @Richard

Comment: Please add this as an answer – showing the fixed type – so others looking for this have help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I help someone last week with same solution.  Use Regex to remove namespace

```
       public DataPDU Deserialize(string filepath)
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataPDU));

            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(true);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath, utf8);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string pattern = "(</?)(\\w+:)";
            string fixedText = Regex.Replace(text,pattern,"$1");
            StringReader fixedReader = new StringReader(fixedText);

            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(fixedReader);  //error raising here
            DataPDU XmlData = (DataPDU)obj;
            reader.Close();
            return XmlData;
        }
```

Comment: Hacking the XML structure is not a fix. It is a workaround that should be reserved for those rare cases when you have an XML parser so primitive it does not support namespaces. This does not apply to .NET's XML support.

Comment: I don' t agree it is a hack.  If you are getting a file from a vendor with a namespace that Net can't handle this may be the only option.

Comment: This isn't a hack, the file format here is defined by the financial trading network so isn't something developers can amend. Still an issue today.